# Java Iterator weblink - skipping links

Tags: java, selenium, iterator

probably a noob question but better to ask, maybe will help someone else too.

I have written a script that utilises Iterator to iterate over some anchor links.  The anchor links are passed to the iterator by cssSelector.  The issue I am having is 2 fold.

Firstly, the first anchor link is SKIPPED and every second anchor link is skipped.

Secondly, when my Regex is found to be true it clicks on the wrong entry.

For example I have a table with the following links:

a
b
c
d
1
2
3
4

If I do a sys out on the loop I get the following:
b
d
2
4
etc...

Can someone point out what I have done wrong, is probably a small mistake I am missing.

The code is as follows:

The method is called by:

```
sc.searchandclick(".d_ich>div>div>div>div>a", ".*test dropbox1.*");
```

and the method is:

```
public String searchandclick(String aCssSelector, String regex) {
    String text = "";


    try {

        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(aCssSelector));
        //System.out.println(list);
        Iterator<WebElement> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            WebElement link = iter.next();
            text = iter.next().getAttribute("title");
            System.out.println(text);
            String regEx = regex;
            //Boolean b = Pattern.matches(regEx, text);

            //if (b == true) {

                //try {
                    //link.click();
                //  break;

                //} catch (Exception e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                //}

            }

        //}

        //return text;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;

}
```

When I look at CSS ireturns the following:

```
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View a submissions">a</a>
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View b submissions">b</a>
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View c submissions">c</a>
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View d submissions">d</a>
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View 1 submissions">1</a>
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View 2 submissions">2</a>
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View 3 submissions">3</a>
<a class="vui-link" href="folder_submissions_users" title="View test dropbox1 submissions">test dropbox1</a>
```

Can someone point out the error of my ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are jumping ahead on the iterator twice within the loop

```
 WebElement link = iter.next();              //next
 text = iter.next().getAttribute("title");   //next again!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Within the `while` loop when you did `WebElement link = iter.next();` you are already on the next WebElement. So in the next line you don't need to use `iter.next()`. All you need to do is `text = link.getAttribute("title");`

So you need to replace:

```
text = iter.next().getAttribute("title");
```

by:

```
text = link.getAttribute("title");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @DebajanB thank a lot! I just couldn't see it where I went wrong arrrgh.  Thanks again